# Exporting results from stationary tests (urca package) from R to excel

Tags: r, export-to-excel

I have conducted ADF, PP and KPSS tests using the urca package. I want to transfer the results from R to excel.
I tried using the 'xlsx' package, but it's library isn't loading 
I also tried using write.csv command but it doesn't export results directly .

**ADF test**

```
x=ur.df(BSE,type="none", selectlags="AIC")
x
summary(x)
```

Please help me to export the results to excel .

Comment: What is the error when loading `xlsx` package. You need to add path of  java.exe to you PATH environment variable

Comment: #1 _" library isn't loading"_ - what error? #2 _"the results"_ - what results exactly, I mean the output of `summary(x)` is probably no table, and Excel is best used for tabular data. #3 Please edit your post and make it a reproducible example - you got example data in `?ur.df`.